# Erro no Django 2.2 - conexão com o mysql

Tags: mysql, python, django

Olá! É o seguinte, estou com um problema para realizar a conexão no mysql com o django. O erro é esse:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
>   Did you install mysqlclient?

A primeira solução que encontrei na internet, foi simplesmente instalar esse módulo com pip install mysqlclient. Sem sucesso, foi me retornado um erro gigante.

> running build_ext
>       building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
>       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Tentei instalar "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools", **sem sucesso.**

A segunda solução que encontrei, foi adicionar as seguintes linhas dentro do arquivo settings.py, logo após instalar com o pip o pymysql.

```
 import pymysql

 pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Isso me retornou o seguinte erro:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.

Eu não faço a mínima ideia do que pode ser ou do que fazer, já que sou iniciante e não tenho muita noção :/

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser? Obrigado e aguardo resposta!

Comment: Você pode rodar tudo com docker, se vc estiver disposto eu posso mostrar uma configuração funcionando. Esse erro aí tem cara de ser problema com a versão sua e do SO, a última mensagem aí diz que vc está com uma versão antiga do `mysqlclient`, tenta colocar a mais nova

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece ser um problema de divergência com as versões do MySQL exigida e a versão instalada na máquina.

**Primeiro passo faça o upgrade do python para última versão.**

**Feito o upgrade** e antes de instalar o pacote [MysqlClient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/). Na página do MysqlClient o fabricante informa que existem pré-requisitos de instalação para o pacote para cada sistema operacional.
 O que você deverá fazer é instalar as bibliotecas de desenvolvimento nescessárias do MysqlClient...

Se o ambiente for **Linux**:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev # Debian / Ubuntu

sudo yum install python-devel mysql-devel # Red Hat / CentOS
```

---

Se o ambiente for **Mac-OS**:

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

---

Se o ambiente for **Windows** siga os passos...

Instale o Wheeler:

```
pip install wheel
```

Então faça o download dos wheels nescessários em http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python. *Por exemplo no Windows 10 64bits baixei o arquivo `mysqlclient‑1.4.2‑cp38‑cp38m‑win_amd64.whl`*

Após o download instale o wheels:

```
pip install mysqlclient‑1.4.2‑cp38‑cp38m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Em windows ainda terá que instalar o [runtime do MSVC](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

---

Concluído esses passo instale o MySqlClient no sistema.

```
pip install --only-binary :all: mysqlclient
```

Comment: Para isso dar certo lembre-se de ter o MySQL instalado no sistema. De preferência atualizado.

Comment: Segui esses passos. Estou num ambiente Windows 10 64bits. Quando fui instalar o arquivo .whl, foi me retornado o seguinte erro: "ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Comment: Tenta outra versão `mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl` ou mais antga

Comment: Tentei todas, e ainda não funcionou... :/

Comment: A resposta está marcada como "aceita" - se ainda não funcionou, desmarque , e pode ser que o autor da resposta acima, ou outra pessoa venha te ajudar. Maracada como aceita, todo mundo vai achar que já foi resolvido e seguir em frente.

Comment: O mérito aqui é resolver o problema e não simplesmente dar uma resposta. Se o problema persiste, **desmarque** a resposta e vamos a outra alternativa.